# Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm trying to create a function that eliminates multiples of a given Integer from a list of Integers, in the form `multiples x [y]`, where x is the given Integer, and y is the list.

Here's what I have:

```
multiples :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
multiples a [] = []
multiples a [b] = filter (\l -> l `mod` a /= 0) [b]
```

`multiples` will fail when called, saying "Non-exhaustive patterns in function multiples". So I used `ghci -Wall` with my file to see what patterns were missing, and it returns this:

```
multiples.hs:2:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `multiples': Patterns not matched: _ (_:_:_)

multiples.hs:2:11: warning: [-Wunused-matches]
    Defined but not used: `a'
```

I get the feeling I'm missing something really simple with line 2, but I'm a bit stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are a couple of things to fix in your function, but I'll start with the one you seem the most confused about: here `[b]` is a pattern matching a *one-element* list, naming its single item `b`. (`[b, c]` would be a pattern matching a two-element list, etc.) It's not a pattern matching an arbitrarily long list of `b`s. GHC is telling you off because you haven't accounted for the case where the function has been given a two-or-more-element list.

If you want to match an arbitrary list of `b`s, omit the square brackets. Additionally, the first line of your function is not necessary because the second line already deals with that case.

```
multiples :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
multiples a bs = filter (\b -> b `mod` a /= 0) bs
```

Or, using a list comprehension,

```
multiples :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
multiples a bs = [b | b <- bs, b `mod` a /= 0]
```

Two more things: I'd name this function `withoutMultiples` because it *filters out* multiples of `a`, and because Haskell functions are curried by default you can omit the `bs` in the `filter` version.

```
withoutMultiples :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
withoutMultiples a = filter (\b -> b `mod` a /= 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - I missed the `=` when copying my code over here. Changing both instances of `[b]` to `bs` fixed the issue!

Answer (score 4):

Your pattern

```
    multiples a [b]
```

expects an Integer (bound to name "a") and list of Integer containing one element (bound to name "b"). Remove square brackets (which will change type of "b" to [Integer]) in this pattern and it should be working. Also you can curry this function to form

```
    multiples a = filter (\l -> l `mod` a /= 0)
```

and omit first pattern as it should be covered by filter function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I missed that `[b]` would imply a one element list. Replacing it with `bs` indeed fixed the issue. The first pattern was added as a result of troubleshooting the non-exhaustive pattern error.

Comment: Fun fact - it is possible to write that function in point-free style, which looks like this `multiples = filter . ((/=) 0 .) . flip mod` Sometimes it's good exercise to look at that and try to understand all the transformations.